# C# Hiding fields from model where xml deserialization points to

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, member-hiding

sI have one controller class, which is having private field of another class which is a model, model which gets data from xml deserialization. Because of this deserialization process I had to create public, parameterless constructor and some public fields-helpers which are simply processing data formats to another types. This processing is so simple that I don't want to re-write and XmlSerialization class using it's interface.
What I want to achieve is to have access to the fields from the model from the interface it inherits from only, but the model has to have public fields - how to hide some of them? They are in the same project. (Whole application is so tiny that dividing it to smaller pieces not always makes sense).

There is an example:

```html
public class Program
{
 public static void RequestHandler
 {
  
  public RequestHandler(string xmlRequest){
  IRequest request = DataModel.ParseXml(xmlRequest);
   
  //now user can use request from IRequest only
  //but when he doesn't know that he has to use IRequest he can easily access and change 
  //values in DataModel properties, I want to prevent such possibility
  
  }   
 }
}

public interface IRequest{
 
 int test_id { get; }
 DateTime description { get; }
 
 IRequest ParseXml(string request);
 bool Validate(IRequest request);
}

public class DataModel : IRequest {
 
 [XmlElement("testId")]
 int test_id { get; set; }
 
 [XmlElement("testId")]
 DateTime description { get; set; }

    public DataModel() {} //this has to be specified to be allowed to use Serialization
                          //I don't want users to be able to use this constructor, however it has to be public 
 
 IRequest static ParseXml(string request){
      
  // Xml Parsing process 
 }
 
 bool Validate(IRequest request) {
  
  //Process of checking if all data are available
 }
 

}
```

Comment: Why do you care? If someone will be using your class via interface there is no problem. If he will use it directly than there is nothing you can do other than create another layer of abstraction.

Comment: I care because I want to prevent other team members from using my libraries in not proper way. I am trying to create code which would be easily understandable.

Comment: Can you give a [simple, concrete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are doing now and what you want to achieve?  Your question is abstract so it's hard to know exactly how to help.  Possibly [explicit interface implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) would meet your needs.

Comment: edited, read the comments, please. I am not allowed to show you the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make your model as 'Internal' and expose all fields only via multiple interfaces and write another class which will expose your model objects via interface. e.g.

```
internal class DataModel : Interface1, Interface2 {

     internal DataModel(_xml)
     {
        this.xml = _xml;
     }

    private xml {get; set;}

    public Interface1.Property1 {get; set;}

    public Interface2.Property2 {get; set;}
}

//expose DataModel only via below Helper class
public class DataModelHelper {

   public Interface1 GetModel_1(string xml)
   {
    Interface1 i1 = new  DataModel(xml);
    return i1;
   }

   public Interface2 GetModel_2(xml)
   {
    Interface2 i2 = new  DataModel(xml);
    return i2;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that XmlSerializer will work with that.

Comment: The question is for internal: internal is for what: the namespace? So when I will save this folder in namespace MyProjectName1.DataModel and define is as internal will it be not accessible for MyProjectName1.* namespaces?

Comment: It should work bcoz xml deserialization is happening inside model and it's completely abstracted from controller.

Comment: It will be accessable within your 'MyProjectName1' assembly i.e. to all namespaces within assembly.

Comment: And my question is about hiding it in MyProjectName1.DataModel only, is it possible with Serialization?